# Efficient lemmatization in scikit-learn TfidfVectorizer?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lemmatization, countvectorizer, tfidfvectorizer

I made slow function `return_lema(tokens)` which converts a list of tokens to list of lemas.

1. When I put it in `build_tokenizer(self)` function from [this
   example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/bicluster/plot_bicluster_newsgroups.html)
   in `TfidfVectorizer`, it takes 37 seconds.
2. However, then I first aqquire vocabulary with `CountVectorizer`,
   input tokens from term-frequency matrix to my `return_lema(tokens)`,
   and then do `TfidfTransformer`, it takes 13 seconds.

The second way is faster due to `return_lema(tokens)` doesn't get repetitive tokens. However, now I can't do correct `min_df` or `max_df` as it is done with `CountVectorizer`.

Is there are way to put my `return_lema(tokens)` somewhere in `TfidfVectorizer` flow, so that it take not documents one by one, but final feature vocabulary before performing `min_df` and `max_df`?

Comment: i don't understand you last paragraph. max_df and min_df are frequency over the whole vocabulary. So i don't understand what do you mean by one by one but the final feature vocabulary, since final vocabulary had been build after go through one by one document :S

Comment: In build_tokenizer from TfidfVectorizer documents are processed sequentially (one after other) and thus my function in there gets repetitive values. When all documents are processed, you get vocabulary from term-document matrix - in this point I want to put my function. Then features are filtered by min_df and max_df. So how to access that point to put my function in?

Comment: Maybe built in a custom transformer that you use between CounterVectorizer (just counter words and build vocab) and TfidifTransformer.

Comment: Do you mean put filter by min_df and max_df function between CountVectorizer and TfidfTransformer? I could, but I wonder if there is a simpler way like build_tokenizer.

Comment: Just with a class that extend [Transformer base class](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.base.TransformerMixin.html#sklearn.base.TransformerMixin) of sklearn you can put in a pipeline flow, i think is quite simple. Sorry i don't have another idea :P